# SSO for MariaDB, Office 365 by keycloak

Tags: active-directory, mariadb, keycloak, single-sign-on

I am trying to Connect MariaDB database from keycloak authentication.
I need to import users from keycloak or office 365 or windows AD.

**What I achived:**
I am able to ldap from windows AD.

**Where I strucked:**
Need to Connect mariadb database with AD users using RBAC.

**Roles:**

Read_access  - select ,execute

Write_access - insert,update

Full_access  - Modify,delete

Any suggestion will be appreciated, Thanks